# Export Selenium browser addon macros into c# (webdriver)

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

Is there a possibility to export a macro from the Selenium Firefox browser extension and run it from a C#/WebDriver application? The goal is to execute the recorded macro and add some c#-programed commands on top, as well as run as aprt of the test suit.

The addon allows exporting the macros in C# only for Selenium RC (version 1) and not WebDriver. One of the possibilities I was thinking about is saving the macros as json (which the addons allows) and running it somehow with WebDriver, although I havn't found a way to do so (the documentation on C# API's is quite scarce).
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have the [latest version](http://seleniumhq.org/download/) of the Selenium IDE. Under Options > Format/Clipboard Format there should be an option for *C# (WebDriver)* and *C# (Remote Control)*. The first one is that you are looking for.